# Type initialization of DataTemplateSelector failed in XAML Designer

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplateselector

I'm using a DataTemplateSelector in my WPF Application. At runtime it works perfectly but when using the XAML Editor an exception is thrown and no preview is displayed.

[image]

My Selector looks like this:

```
public class DynamicTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplatesProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Templates", typeof(TemplateCollection), typeof(DataTemplateSelector), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new TemplateCollection(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

    public static TemplateCollection GetTemplates(UIElement element)
    {
        return (TemplateCollection)element.GetValue(TemplatesProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTemplates(UIElement element, TemplateCollection collection)
    {
        element.SetValue(TemplatesProperty, collection);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Overriden base method to allow the selection of the correct DataTemplate
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item for which the template should be retrieved</param>
    /// <param name="container">The object containing the current item</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="DataTemplate"/> to use when rendering the <paramref name="item"/></returns>
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        ////This should ensure that the item we are getting is in fact capable of holding our property
        ////before we attempt to retrieve it.
        if (!(container is UIElement))
        {
            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }

        ////First, we gather all the templates associated with the current control through our dependency property
        TemplateCollection templates = GetTemplates(container as UIElement);
        if (templates == null || templates.Count == 0)
        {
            base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }

        ////Then we go through them checking if any of them match our criteria
        foreach (Template template in templates)
        {
            ////In this case, we are checking whether the type of the item
            ////is the same as the type supported by our DataTemplate
            if (template.Value.IsInstanceOfType(item))
            {
                ////And if it is, then we return that DataTemplate
                return template.DataTemplate;
            }
        }

        ////If all else fails, then we go back to using the default DataTemplate
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

If tried to use the DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool Flag in my Selector but without success...

```
  public class TemplateCollection : List<Template>
  {
  }




  public class Template : DependencyObject
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(Type), typeof(Template));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DataTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(Template));

public Type Value
{
  get
  {
    return (Type)this.GetValue(ValueProperty);
  }

  set
  {
    this.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
  }
}

public DataTemplate DataTemplate
{
  get
  {
    return (DataTemplate)this.GetValue(DataTemplateProperty);
  }

  set
  {
    this.SetValue(DataTemplateProperty, value);
  }
}
```

}

Comment: You set `TargetType` to `ContentControl`. `ContentControl` is not automatically get properties from your own object.

Comment: Ok, but how can i set it then? Thanks for the help...

Comment: Usually it is not a good idea to initialize default dependency property value with a mutable reference type, it can lead to a bunch of issues and it also can cause the problem in the designer. Pass `null` instead of `new TemplateCollection()` in dependency property declaration if it doesn't solve your problem post the `TemplateCollection` class.

Comment: I have tried this but it didn't help. The TemplateCollectio is very simple helper class. I edit the question

Comment: I think you can try to define your templates in the object resources in xaml. And load templates in the `TemplateSelector` from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the issue:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplatesProperty = 
DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Templates", typeof(TemplateCollection), 
typeof(DataTemplateSelector), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
new TemplateCollection(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
```

You are registering the attached property for the base class `DataTemplateSelector` instead of the class you are using the property in XAML `DynamicTemplateSelector` which seems to break the designer.